# Javascript var that contains jquery Dom elements information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, slick.js

In my current development i use the slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

There is an event that returns a variable in js called slick

when I print the variable (through console.log) i get this

[image]

so as i can read it i have slick>slides>0

How can i access the classes of the slick>slides>0 div in js?

what I need is to get that div in js / jquery so that i can pause the slider for video slides and unpause after playing video

Whats's the syntax for this in js / jquery ?

I have tried slick.slides.0 ; slick.slides[0]

Without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `slick['$slides'][0]` or `slick.$slides[0]` work?

Comment: both turn out 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: Be sure to try to access that variable using the uppercase at the start, it can make difference: `Slick` not `slick`

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to try this from Slick's `init` event handler. Maybe those element references don't exist when you're trying to grab them.

Slick with AngularJS is a whole other beast. You basically need to be sure everything has rendered before you slick it. If you're not using the AngularJS Slick library, you need to put the slick command in an ng-init callback.